# How to control the CPU utilization of a thread at runtime?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, cpu-usage

The following code is my attempt to do that. However i do understand this is not an elegant approach. Could someone point me in the right direction. Any code-sampe is welcome. Thank you for reading.

[image: snap shot of application]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown_CPU.Value));
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double currentUtilization = (double)e.UserState;
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { currentUtilization.ToString() });
        textBoxCurrentUtilization.Text = currentUtilization.ToString();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int CPU_utilization = (int)e.Argument;

        while (true)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
                return;

            Thread.Sleep(CPU_utilization);
            int total = 0;
            Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            foreach (ProcessThread pt in p.Threads)
            {
                total += pt.TotalProcessorTime.Milliseconds;
                if (pt.Id == (int)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId())
                {
                    TimeSpan ts = pt.TotalProcessorTime;
                    double percentage = ((double)(ts.Milliseconds + 1) / total) * 100;
                    worker.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(percentage), percentage);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void numericUpDown_CPU_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        worker.CancelAsync();

        while (worker.IsBusy)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        int desiredUtilization = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(100 - numericUpDown_CPU.Value));
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(desiredUtilization); //restart worker
    }

    void SetText(string text)
    {
        this.textBoxCurrentUtilization.Text = text;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm unaware of being able to specify exactly how much CPU you want your application to be able to use. I know that you can set a specific thread's priority, and that will help throttle a process' CPU usage. Documentation on [Threads can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) and documentation on setting the [Priority can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority(v=vs.110).aspx). I would make sure that this is something you're really wanting to do, and have a specific use case before doing so.

Comment: 'Application.DoEvents()' loop :((

Comment: What @Cameron says.  If the thread/s are doing useful work, why try to throttle them?  If they are not doing useful work, change the design so that they don't do useless work.  If they are doing useful work but it's CPU-intensive and so unacceptably lowers the response to the GUI or impacts other apps, lower the priority of the threads so that they only soak up what CPU is left after the other threads have executed.  Oh - and get rid of the DoEvents loop - there is no need for such ugliness.  Replace with Invoke/BeginInvoke signaling.

Comment: And don't set the priority on pool threads. That means threads created with `QueueUserWorkItem`, any `Task` threads, `BackgroundWorker`, etc. If you need to set priority, then create and manage your own threads (i.e. the `Thread` class).

Comment: @JimMischel - if setting the priority of pool theads, (there ought to be an AfterCreation() event or some virtual method of overriding the ctor), is either impractical or not recommended, the pool designers need a slap on the head:)

Comment: @MartinJames: Perhaps. Although the original design of the thread pool was for tasks that wouldn't take very long. The recommendation was that if you needed a long-running task, you would create and manage your own thread. I suspect a lot of that had to do with the fairly limited thread pool that was available prior to Windows Vista, although I don't know if that's how the .NET Threadpool was implemented. One could argue that the design should be revisited, but I suspect it's not high on the priority list.

Comment: Thank you all for the interesting comments. @MartinJames i need to learn more about DoEvents vs Invoke signalling...

Comment: @Cameron One use case would be a thread in a mobile-phone that should under normal circumstance use less than say 5% of CPU time but on receiving a signal from another application should be permitted to use say up to 50% of CPU time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the amount of CPU for your process by creating a job object where you can set the limits via SetInformationJobObject. There you need to fill out the structure [JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

This feature is only available on Windows versions >= 8. As an alternative to setting a hard limit you can also register a callback when the CPU rate is exceeded. There you could e.g. pause your worker threads if you are sure that they are the main source of CPU activity.